# Receiving webhook over https in django development server tunneled using ngrok

Tags: django, webhooks, ngrok

I need to test a payment integration, where the payment service sends a webhook when payment is successful. The url for the webhook must be `https://xxx-ngrock.io/paymentNotification`. In this case, I cannot change the url to `http`. My problem is, I cannot receive this webhook because:

1. In development mode django does not allow traffic over https only over http
2. I tunnel to my development server using this command `./ngrok http https://localhost:8000` which I guess should forward the https traffic, but I have no way of testing it since the development server does not accept traffic over http in the first place.

Additional comments. Currently the ngrok forwarding map where both traffic from `http` and `https` are mapped to the https internal traffic that Django does not support for its development serveer.

```
ngrok by @inconshreveable                                                                                               (Ctrl+C to quit)
                                                                                                                                        
Session Status                online                                                                                                    
Account                       JianDk (Plan: Free)                                                                                       
Version                       2.3.40                                                                                                    
Region                        United States (us)                                                                                        
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040                                                                                     
Forwarding                    http://3304-94-147-65-45.ngrok.io -> https://localhost:8000                                               
Forwarding                    https://3304-94-147-65-45.ngrok.io -> https://localhost:8000                                              
                                                                                                                                        
Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90                                                               
                              7       0       0.06    0.02    0.00    0.01                                                              
                                                                                                                                        
HTTP Requests                                                                                                                           
-------------                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                        
GET /favicon.ico                                                                                                                        
GET /                                                                                                                                   
GET /favicon.ico                                                                                                                        
GET /                                                                                                                                   
GET /                                                                                                                                   
GET /favicon.ico                                                                                                                        
GET /
```

Comment: ngrok should have https, in fact, I used ngrok for the same purpose and it worked!

Comment: so the problem is not with ngrok? The way I started the ngrok should allow https traffic to be tunneled to my development server?

Comment: yes yes, are there any logs logged?

Comment: I am quite new to ngrok. They provide a web interface to check the traffic http://localhost:4040/inspect/http , I am not sure if it will check the traffic over https. The main problem here is I need a way for my django development server to accept traffic over https

Comment: ngrok will provide a https and a http urls for which may be tunneled to your development server

Comment: let me answer for you to see my screenshots

Comment: can you share the command of how you started this tunnel? It is different from mine where both http and https are directed to https://localhost:8000

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241312/discussion-between-jxw-and-emanuel-sanga).

Answer (score 0):

ngrok will provide one http and one https links for you to tunnel your dev server to.

[image: So tou should use the one with https]

If I have misunderstood your question, please add a comment!